# Risk of visa refusal?

Tags: visas, overstaying

My question is special, I hope from the bottom of my heart to get answers.

I lived 6 years in France on a regular basis, and after several problems I found myself in an irregular situation for a year and a half. I beg you not to judge me, the pain is still present. I ended up leaving the country voluntarily and I returned to my country of origin. I was never arrested or deported, I left the country voluntarily. I suppose that during the border police at the airport the policeman probably put me on their database.

I would therefore like to know if the immigration officers of the embassies of all countries could know this kind of information. Can they know that I have been in an irregular situation in France? Can they deny me a visa to Canada (or other) because of this? Am I internationally registered? If so, am I stuck for life? How can this information be "deleted" from their database? How do I get a visa again?

I have no intention of making the same mistake again. I would simply like to live legally somewhere and respect the visa deadlines.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, only the Schengen countries have automated access to their immigration database. There may be an alert for you on the SIS for the purpose of refusing you entry: https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system/alerts-and-data-in-the-sis_en You should ask make use of a freedom of information request to find out if they have you on that database or not. Canada should not be able to find that out (unless they have enough of reason to use resources to find out manually pursuant to bilateral agreements which I'm not aware of).

However, you would be bound to disclose this to relevant authorities if asked if you have ever overstayed or violated conditions of your visa in any country. Only a handful of countries ask for that.

The main problem you will face is proving strong ties to your country of origin. It will take a few years of living there for you to develop ties strong enough to qualify for most non-immigrant visas.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick response. Second, how will I be able to access the website you sent me? Isn't that supposed to be confidential? 

Yes, precisely in relation to the questions asked of me in relation to this, I have a question, I was looking at the visa for Japan and I see this question but I have difficulty understanding the meaning:

" Have you ever:

been deported or removed from Japan or any country for overstaying your visa or violating any law or regulation? "

Comment: Basically they ask me if I have been deported from a country for exceeding the visa period or breaking a law ? (2 conditions)

Or
if I was deported for exceeding the visa period OR if I broke a law?

Because if it is the first meaning I answer"no" (I was never deported) but if it is the second meaning I must answer "yes" because yes I broke the law.

What do you think, please?

And thanks :) ( sorry for my english)

Comment: @Mey You need to contact the French authorities for that information. Also, the answer the question about deportation is no. Deportation is a a formal order to go and not return.

Comment: If the question is "have you broken the law" then the honest answer is "yes". So you have to decide if you are going to lie or tell the truth. This is a gamble and you are researching here to try to estimate odds. Your worst case outcome is to get a refusal for lying: this will likely get you a long time ban.

Comment: @greatone I come here for the spirit of a straight answer to a straight question regardless of my personal views.

Comment: thank you for your answer. No I wouldn't lie I know it's serious, I just wanted to know how this question should be understood, it's not clear enough

Comment: @user16259 can you honestly say you've never broken the law? Also, immigration offences are usually dealt with administratively with no criminal liability. Also if the Canadians don't ask the OP does not need to volunteer information. If they have no access to Schengen, he has a better chance of success.

Comment: @Mey you were obviously not removed or deported for violating or breaking a law or regulation because you were never removed or deported. Many people break laws and regulations and not all of them have consequences even if caught. You can break a regulation of a private club and that still be breaking a regulation. Only certain criminal offences cause removal or deportation in the context asked by the Japanese.

Comment: @greatone I'm not offering an opinion on whether the question asker should lie or not, I am just summarising their options. Their optimal course of action may be to lie, if the likelihood of getting caught is low and/or they are willing to accept the consequences of getting caught.

Comment: @user16259 I would agree with you but he doesn't need to lie at all. At least in the Japanese visa form. Or the Canadian one.

Comment: for the Japanese visa if the question I quoted above means"I was deported" I will say"no" it is not a lie !
But in this case, maybe it was me who misinterpreted the question I'm afraid they think I lied!